# How do I tell react-refresh-webpack-plugin to use a non-standard domain name? (shakapacker, react_on_rails)

Tags: ssl, react-on-rails, shakapacker

So I'm building an app where a dev requirement is to develop locally on SSL/TSL self-signed certificates. I do this by adding an entry for a fake domain, like `abc.localhost` , to my `/etc/hosts` file

Using

rails 7.0.6
react_on_rails ~> 13.4
shakapacker ~> 7.0

I have a special setup which boots my Rails server telling Puma to listen for SSL connections using the self-signed certificate.

using this Procfile.dev:

```
# Procfile for development using HMR
# You can run these commands in separate shells
rails: bin/rails s -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?key=config/ssl/abc.localhost.key&cert=config/ssl/abc.localhost.crt'
wp-client: bin/shakapacker-dev-server
wp-server: SERVER_BUNDLE_ONLY=yes bin/shakapacker --watch
```

Take note that this setup also has these lines in `development.rb`

```
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.hosts << "abc.localhost"
  config.action_cable.url = "wss://abc.localhost/cable"
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ "*" ]
```

WHen I go to https://abc.localhost:3000, the Shakapacker hello world comes up fine:

[image]

but in the console I am getting `WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:3035/ws' failed:`

I believe this is caused by the react-refresh-webpack-plugin, specifically, it looks like this plugin is looking for the websocket at localhost:3035 when it should be looking for it at `abc.localhost:3035`

can I fix the react-refresh-webpack-plugin (shakapacker/react_on_rails) setup to either respect the `config.action_cable.url` setting or set it explicitly to my non-standard domain?

[image]

Example app can be found here:

https://github.com/jasonfb/TestShakapackerSSL